# Why does Xcode use the old build path after moving a project's containing directory?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have created a simple OSX Command Line App project with Xcode 6.3, called **Foo**, and set the location of **Foo** to **~/Desktop**. Building and running the project is fine. To be clear, the project path is **~/Desktop/Foo/Foo.xcodeproj**.

If I move the project's containing directory **~/Desktop/Foo** to, say **~/Desktop/tmp/Foo**, open **~/Desktop/tmp/Foo/Foo.xcodeproj**, and then build the project, I see that Xcode creates **~/Desktop/Foo/build/** and so on. It seems that Xcode is still using the old build path rather than the build directory that is relative to the project (**~/Desktop/tmp/Foo/build/**).

Why is this? I am using a typical installation of Xcode and have not modified any configuration of Xcode nor the project or its build settings. Xcode 5 definitely did not behave this way.

Yes, the project has been cleaned.

Comment: did you try to clean the project first and then rebuild after moving it?

Comment: Yep. I've updated the question to mention this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only attribute this to accumulated cruft after installing, removing, and updating Xcode to various 6.x betas over the past year.

After deleting Xcode configuration via `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`, things are behaving as expected.